How to Implement Session Threshold Check in Azure AD B2C Custom Policy for High-Traffic Scenarios?
I'm using Azure AD B2C with a custom policy for authentication and need to handle peak burst scenarios effectively.
During high-traffic events, such as promotions, I want to manage session thresholds to prevent system overload.
Objective:

Implement a session check during user login attempts.
Monitor the current session count using Azure AD B2C logs.
Redirect users to a "Sorry, Try Later" page if the session count exceeds 10,000 user session.

My questions:

How can I monitor the current session count using Azure AD B2C logs?
What is the best way to check if the session count exceeds 10,000 during a user login attempt?
How can I implement the redirection to a "Sorry, Try Later" page when the threshold is exceeded?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!


I want to manage session thresholds to prevent system overload - will B2C explode at a certain number of sessions? Genuinely curious.
